# My code keep printing the same line of information

Tags: python

I want to try making Simple bible search, I use BIBLE.txt which already include all of bible. This is my code:

```
with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
    count = [0]
    for line in Bible:
        index = line[:8].split()
        Book = index[0].strip().upper()
        chapter, verse = map(str.strip, index[1].split(":"))
        index_dictionary[(Book, chapter, verse)] = count

Bible = open("BIBLE.txt")
while True:
    search_engine = input(
                          "Book list: Ge(Genesis), Ex(Exodus), Le(Leviticus), Nu(Number), De(Deuteronomy), "
                          "Jos(Joshua) \n "
                          "jg(Judges)"
                          "(or x to exit)      \n"
                          "Input Book(Abbreviation only!):Chapter:verse     \n "

    )

    if search_engine == "x":
        print("see you next time")
        break
    Book, chapter, verse = map(str.strip, search_engine.split(":"))
    keyword = (Book.upper(), chapter, verse)
    if keyword in index_dictionary:
        bible = Bible.readline()
        print(bible)
Bible.close()
```

It seems I need to add count += len(line) below index_dictionary, but if i put it, int object is not iterable

No matter what it is, it will show ge1:1

Comment: You never change the position of the file.  You always read the first line.  What's the point of your index?  You might as well save the text of the verse in your index, rather than storing the useless `count` list.  If you stored the text directly, you could just `print(index_dictionary[keyword])`.

Comment: @TimRoberts how do you stored the text directly?

Comment: oh alright, its getting better now, I can now print All of genesis, oops no it didnt

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: ohh okay, i just knew about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening Bible.txt two times in a row and your count does not increase in the loops.

```py
with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
    count = [0]
    for line in Bible:
        index = line[:8].split()
        Book = index[0].strip().upper()
        chapter, verse = map(str.strip, index[1].split(":"))
        index_dictionary[(Book, chapter, verse)] = count

Bible = open("BIBLE.txt")
```

Instead you can do:

```py
with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
    for i, line in enumerate(Bible):
        index = line[:8].split()
        Book = index[0].strip().upper()
        chapter, verse = map(str.strip, index[1].split(":"))
        index_dictionary[(Book, chapter, verse)] = i
```

And in your if-block you say that if you have keyword in your index. Read the first line in Bible.

```py
 if keyword in index_dictionary:
        bible = Bible.readline()
        print(bible)
```

`.readline()` only reads one line per use. So it starts with the first line and the next time you call it you will get the next line and so on.

If you want to load a specific row you either need to save a list of all lines when reading and creating your `index_dictionary` or just do the search engine matching instead of creating your index.

With index (using your `index_dictionary` to find which lines you want to print) matching:

```py
with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
    for i, line in enumerate(Bible):
        if i in index_list
             print(line)
```

Using the search engine inside the reading operation:

```py
with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
    for i, line in enumerate(Bible):
        index = line[:8].split()
        Book = index[0].strip().upper()
        chapter, verse = map(str.strip, index[1].split(":"))
        index_dictionary[(Book, chapter, verse)] = i 
        if keyword in index_dictionary:
            print(line)
```

A sample of what your new code could look like:

```py
while True:
    search_engine = input(
                          "Book list: Ge(Genesis), Ex(Exodus), Le(Leviticus), Nu(Number), De(Deuteronomy), "
                          "Jos(Joshua) \n "
                          "jg(Judges)"
                          "(or x to exit)      \n"
                          "Input Book(Abbreviation only!):Chapter:verse     \n "

    )

    if search_engine == "x":
        print("see you next time")
        break
    Book, chapter, verse = map(str.strip, search_engine.split(":"))
    keyword = (Book.upper(), chapter, verse)

    with open("BIBLE.txt") as Bible:
        for i, line in enumerate(Bible):
             index = line[:8].split()
             Book = index[0].strip().upper()
             chapter, verse = map(str.strip, index[1].split(":"))
             index_dictionary[(Book, chapter, verse)] = i 
             if keyword in index_dictionary:
                 print(line)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help, but, now that it no longer printing genesis 1:1, instead it printed the whole bible everytime

Comment: can you please show me how its done here  https://replit.com/join/lwssawdhpt-justin-habelhab

Comment: especially where to put the if i index_list print line

Comment: Updated the answer to include a complete sample code

Comment: what is the def(main) for?

Comment: it always error because of that

Comment: You can replace it with `while True:`
I edited the answer now to use `while True:` but I think you should reconsider using infinite loops until you are certain about what you are doing.

Comment: I FINALLY GOT IT! AHAAAA THANKS REGRETFUL!!!!! for people who get the same task as me in the future below the print(line), dont forget to break!